# Searching a CSV file in Python - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

Problems with my code... when I execute it in Python and input a valid number, it comes up with "IndexError: list index out of range" even when its valid or invalid. I want it to print row[0] and row [1] if the number is between 0 & 9 else print out an error message.

```
import csv

number=input("Enter num: ")

with open("myfile.txt", "r") as file:
    fileReader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in fileReader:
        for i in range (0,10):
            if row[i] == number:
                print(row [0], row [1])
    else:
        print ("Error")

file.close()
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What are you trying to do with the line `if row[i] == number:` ?

Comment: if the row[0 - 10] is equal to the input asked at the beginning then print(row [0], row [1]), else 'error' @avysk

Comment: Does you row contain 10 elements? Print row before the `for i in range(0, 10)` loop.

Comment: Maybe it could help to see how is the file 'myfile.txt'

Comment: Run this with the `-i` option, for example, `python3 -i myscript.py`, it will drop you into the python shell when the error hits. You can view your variables to see if they have the data you think they should have. If this is python 3, be aware that `number` is a string, not an int.

Answer (score 0):

What you asked for was to print `row[0]` and `row[1]` if the input value is between 0 and 9, but what you are doing is printing `row[0]` and `row[1]` if the input value matches a value stored in `row` between `row[0]` and `row[9]`. You also are assuming that `row` will contain 10 items (depending on your input, maybe this is an acceptable assumption, I don't know).

This will print `row[0]` and `row[1]` (for every row) if the input value is between 0 and 9. It assumes that each row contains at least two items.

```
import csv

number=input("Enter num: ")

if number >= 0 and number <= 9:
    with open("myfile.txt", "r") as file:
        fileReader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in fileReader:
            print(row [0], row [1])
else:
    print ("Error")

file.close()
```